# Adding entire directory tree to tomcat shared classloader

Tags: tomcat, classloader, directory-tree

For example Ant provides option to add entire directory tree to classpath with configuration like "**/*.jar in fileset/include tag.
Is it possible in tomcat that all jar files in entire directory tree with subdirectories are scanned for *.jar files and added to classloader
Caucho Resin [www.caucho.com](http://www.caucho.com) has option in configuration file.
one can add tree-loader tag to include entire directory in classloader.

Comment: I'm wondering what problem that would be supposed to solve. Just package a web application of you want to publish on tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not support this out of the box.